# BeautifulSoup returns 'none'

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I accept to get h2-tag text but it shows me 'none'. It exists.
I have tried to changed the page.content 'html.parser to lxml' so and so on. Still it's not working.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {"User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 
Safari/537.36"}
url = 'http://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/54115'
page = requests.get(url,headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find('div', class_='col-xs-12').h2
print(div)
```

I have tried to change page content in xml after that that it shows `elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()`

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what you're trying to do? What is the `.h2` for?

Answer (score 0):

To find an `<h2>` Element *inside* of the `<div>`, you can use another `.find()` method on the `<div>` that you're finding:

```py
div = soup.find('div', class_='col-xs-12')
heading = div.find('h2')
```

Comment: Great, happy for you @RohitDalal :) Please accept the answer that solved your challenge, that way other people with the same question can quickly find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use select_one and use descendant combinator to get child h2 of that parent class

```
soup.select_one('div.col-xs-12 h2').text
```

Comment: yes, It's working `C:\Users\ABC\Desktop>python first_scraping_solve.py `
**Output** `Search by ZIP, address, city, or county:`